# How can I integrate Open-CV with Mathematica?

Tags: image-processing, mathlink-or-wstp, interoperability, java, librarylink

I would like to run Open-CV functions from within Mathematica, can anyone figure out how to do this?

Comment: Seems like it's been done before on a pc (see [here](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/LibraryLink/tutorial/ImageProcessing.html)). I'm trying to get it working on a mac...

Comment: I note some example [here](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/LibraryLink/tutorial/ImageProcessing.html.zh) in documentation

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Please take a look at the file `image_external.c.` that you can find in your installation with the command

```
FileNames["image_external.c", {$InstallationDirectory}, Infinity]
```

Therein, everything you want to know is described. When it comes down to compiling, then you need to ensure you have the development files for `opencv` and `libraw` installed and you know the places, where the header-files `"cv.h"`, `"highgui.h"`, `"imgproc_c.h"` and `"libraw.h"` are stored.

Then you can compile the `image_external.c` example with a command similar to

```
Get["CCompilerDriver`"];

CreateLibrary[{"/home/patrick/tmp/ocv/image_external.c"},"imageLib",
  "IncludeDirectories" -> { "/usr/include/opencv", 
      "/usr/include/opencv2/imgproc","/usr/include/libraw"}]
```

---

#### How-to for Mac OS X

Although the approach for OS X is similar, you have to adapt some things. Most importantly you need to know where the include files and the libraries for `opencv` and `libraw` are stored. If you don't have them, then you can install them with e.g. [MacPorts](https://www.macports.org/). To find this out, there has always been a nice tool on Unix like systems: `pkg-config`. Here is how you call it in a terminal to get the includes and libraries for `opencv`:

```
pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv
```

Using this command, you can build your final *Mathematica* call in a minute. Here it is for my machine:

```
CreateLibrary[{"/Users/patrick/tmp/image_external.c"}, "imageLib", 
 "IncludeDirectories" -> {"/opt/local/include", 
   "/opt/local/include/opencv", "/opt/local/include/opencv2/imgproc", 
   "/opt/local/include/libraw"}, 
 "LibraryDirectories" -> {"/opt/local/lib"}, 
 "Libraries" -> {"opencv_calib3d", "opencv_contrib", "opencv_core", 
   "opencv_features2d", "opencv_flann", "opencv_gpu", 
   "opencv_highgui", "opencv_imgproc", "opencv_legacy", "opencv_ml", 
   "opencv_nonfree", "opencv_objdetect", "opencv_photo", 
   "opencv_stitching", "opencv_superres", "opencv_ts", "opencv_video",
    "opencv_videostab", "raw", "stdc++"}]
```

Comment: CreateLibrary[...] is giving the error: CreateLibrary::cmperr: Compile error: /Users/mike/Library/Mathematica/SystemFiles/LibraryResources/MacOSX-x86-64/Working-Michaels-MacBook-Pro-28562-2017858304-56/test.c:1:1: error: expected identifier or '(' >>

Comment: `DLLEXPORT` is a C-define! It has nothing to do with windows except that has *dll* in its name. Please look at the file `WolframLibrary.h` to see how it is defined on Mac.

Comment: lib = CreateLibrary[
 "/Users/mike/tmp/image_external.c"
 ,"image_external"
 ,"Language"->"C++"
]

Comment: What options are required in CreateLibrary for this to work on the mac? I've tried just about every possible combination... Are you using a mac @halirutan?

Comment: The Compile error above indicates that Mathematica is trying to copy the file over into a temp directory but failing... no?

Comment: @M.R. Yes, I'm working under OSX and Linux. First of all, don't you use any IDE like [xcode](https://developer.apple.com/xcode/) or [NetBeans](https://netbeans.org/features/cpp/)? Compiling code from within Mathematica is a nice feature, but for development it is always nicer to have a real *development environment*. Wouldn't it be better to first try to compile this on the commandline?

Comment: @harlirutan Yes I use both of those. If it's not too hard perhaps you can post a makefile or a xcode project that does a hello world for using opencv function inside Mathematica?

Comment: @M.R. Do you see that when providing a *file* for `CreateLibrary` you need to put the filename in braces! Like `CreateLibrary[{"image_external.c"}, "imageLib"]`. Other than that, I'm sure you need to specify where you have the opencv-lib and its headers installed.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/19993/discussion-between-halirutan-and-m-r).

Comment: Fixed the problem thanks to our discussion, the linker problems were cause by homebrew, I switched to macports and everything works! Thanks!

Comment: I have included the information of our chat into the answer so that later visitors will find them easily.

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to make a short comment to the above answer by @halirutan, but had to write an answer due to lack of reputation.
In the OS X solution, "Libraries" should include all the libs from "pkg-config" as well as "raw" and "stdc++". Then, it generates the lib charmingly. The following could generate the libs for me:

```
strConfig = Import["!" <> "/opt/local/bin/pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv", "Text"];
strLib = StringSplit[strConfig][[4 ;;]];
libs = StringDrop[#, 2] & /@ strLib;
Join[libs, {"raw", "stdc++"}]
```

Results:

```
{"opencv_shape","opencv_stitching","opencv_objdetect","opencv_superres","opencv_videostab","opencv_calib3d","opencv_features2d","opencv_highgui","opencv_videoio","opencv_imgcodecs","opencv_video","opencv_photo","opencv_ml","opencv_imgproc","opencv_flann","opencv_core","raw","stdc++"}
```